# Is there an alternative representation for $E[\max\{X,Y\}]$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we have $X,Y$ i.i.d. Is there a simplified form of $E[\max\{X,Y\}]$? Is it just $\max\{E[X],E[Y]\}$? That doesn't seem right, because the latter would just be $E[X]$, and it seems like taking a max should increase the expectation.

Here's what I have so far:

$$\begin{align}
E[\max\{X,Y\}] &= \int\int \max\{x,y\}p(x)p(y)dxdy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)\left[x\int_{-\infty}^xp(y)dy + \int_x^{\infty}yp(y)dy \right]dx
\end{align}$$

The term on the left is kind of $xP(x>y)$ and on the right it's sort of $E[Y|Y>X]$ but I don't really know how to simplify this.

If it's relevant, I ask because I'm trying to understand [this paper](http://www.nber.org/papers/w9109.pdf).

Comment: Clearly $E[\max\{X,Y\}]$ is not $\max\{E[X],E[Y]\}$ in general; e.g. consider $X,Y$ being the values on a pair of (distinguishable) dice. $\max(E(X),E(Y))=3.5$, yet $E(\max(X,Y))>3.5$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy enough to see that $\max\{X,Y\}=\frac{X + Y + |X - Y|} 2$ which gets you an expression for the expectation of the max  in terms of the two means and the L1 distance between $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. with (**CDF**) $F(t) = P(X \leq t)$ and (**PMF**) $m(t) = P(X = t)$,
$$
E[\max(X,Y)] = 2 E[X\cdot F(X)] - E[X\cdot m(X)]
$$
You can derive this expression by breaking the expectation into three parts – the third part comes from the possibility that $X=Y$.
If $X$ has continuous distribution, then $m(\cdot) = 0$ and the above becomes
$$
E[\max(X,Y)] = 2 E[X\cdot F(X)]
$$
This is the "simplest" expression possible (without further assumptions about the distribution of $X$).  Occasionally, it is helpful to instead consider:
$$
E[\min(X,Y)] + E[\max(X,Y)] = E(X) + E(Y)
$$
For instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent Exponential random variables, then you can more easily compute the expectation of the minimum.